# How to parse the AbsoluteUri along with LocalPath only?

Tags: powershell-5.0

Suppose I have the following

```
[uri]$URL = "https://www.example.com/folder/folder2"
```

I would like to get this part along with the first local path, i.e. `https://www.example.com/folder`

In other words, I dont want folder2 etc... because i plan to append this portion to an api path, so eventually i'd have something like `$URL + "/api/v2.0/"` or `https://www.example.com/folder/api/v2.0/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using `-split`

```
($URL -split "folder2")[0]
```

this gives `https://www.example.com/folder/`